# How to parse a lua file in php

Tags: php, lua

How would I gather an associative array from a LUA file using PHP?

The lua file I am trying to parse is formatted like this:

```
Server =
{
    MaxPlayers                  = 5000,

    BindIP                      = "",

    BindPort                    = 7777,

    Timeout                     = 10000,

    Name                        = "Example Server",

    Description                 = "No description available.",

    Password                    = "",

    Announce                    = true,

    SyncUpdate                  = 180
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no native support for reading Lua files, but as Sverri stated, a PECL extension does exist if you feel like installing it.

Alternatively, there's a [nice little WoW Lua configuration file reader project](https://code.google.com/p/wowlp/) that has a useful Parser.php file inside which will be able to read it into an array.

Answer (score -3):

[php.net/lua](http://php.net/lua).

If in doubt, you can just:

```
http://php.net/[PUT_IT_HERE]
```

Comment: :/  Interesting.  Then wouldn't it be better to do: <input type="text" onchange="location.href='//php.net/'+this.value" /> ?

Comment: -1. The PHP documentation is lacking and this is not a core PHP extension. And no, you can't just "PUT_IT_HERE."

Comment: @EvanDarwin 1) The documentation is better than nothing; 2) so what, if it is not a core extension?; 3) Yes, you can. You will get the search page if the URL is not mapped to something.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen There's very little documentation besides the arguments, PECL is a PITA and pear is becoming deprecated, as well as the project has been untouched for almost a year. https://github.com/laruence/php-lua . And if it takes you to the search page that means that there's nothing there to find (according to what you suggested).